# Show and Hide-method won't work on buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hide, show

I've created two buttons which purpose is to either show och hide a paragraph. But it won't work, i'm pretty confused at the moment.

HTML-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="sv-se">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>My Web Page</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="show.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
  <p class="para">Click on button to show or hide text</p>

    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <button id="show">Show</button>
 </body>
```

And here is my Javascript-code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".para").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $(".para").show();
    });
 )};
```

Comment: ``$(document).ready(function()`` should probably be ``$(document).ready(function(){`` (note the missing ``{``)

Comment: It's always good to check console. There you will see error if there's any wrong syntax .

Comment: I understand that, however my i didn't forgot the { in my code just when i copied the code here. This solution don't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `{}` in your code .Try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide").click(function(){
   $(".para").hide();
  });

$("#show").click(function(){
$(".para").show();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

See your brackets, they are wrongly coded! You should use the below syntax:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

> As of [jQuery 3.0](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), only the above syntax is recommended instead of `ready` as the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the `.ready()` method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior.

```js
$(function(){

  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".para").hide();
  });
  
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".para").show();
  });

  
}); // <------ This brace was wrongly coded in your code!
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="para">Click on button to show or hide text</p>

    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <button id="show">Show</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing brace in your script, try this..

```js
$(document).on('click', '#hide', function(){
      $(".para").hide();
});
$(document).on('click', '#show', function(){
      $(".para").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="sv-se">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
  <p class="para">Click on button to show or hide text</p>
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <button id="show">Show</button>
 </body>
```

alse refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/3164682) for better understanding of Click vs on.click in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, this solutions works. I just wonder what is the benefit of writing the code this way? Im new in Javascript/JQuery as you might understand.